# Google Cloud Storage create pub sub notification

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to create a pub/sub notification using PHP. I have a project and a service account. My code looks like:

```
use Google\Cloud\Core\Iam\PolicyBuilder;
use Google\Cloud\PubSub\PubSubClient;
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

self::$storage_client = new StorageClient(
                                    [
            'projectId' => "MY PROJECT ID",
            'keyFile'   => json_decode(file_get_contents("PATH TO MY KEYFILE", true)
                                    ]
                                 );

$pubSub = new PubSubClient(
   [ 'projectId' => "MY PROJECT ID"
);

$serviceAccountEmail = self::$storage_client->getServiceAccount();

$topicName = 'projects/MY PROJECT ID/topics/thumbnail-service-1';
$topic = $pubSub->topic( $topicName );

$iam = $topic->iam();

// --> Error happens here:
$updatedPolicy = (new PolicyBuilder( $iam->policy() ))
    ->addBinding('roles/pubsub.publisher', [ "serviceAccount:$serviceAccountEmail" ])
    ->result();

$iam->setPolicy( $updatedPolicy );

$notification = $bucket->createNotification( $topicName,
    ['event_types' => [
        'OBJECT_FINALIZE',
        'OBJECT_DELETE',
        ]
    ]
    );
```

I think I"m trying to create the topic named, but I get this error:

```
exception 'Exception' with message 'exception 'Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\NotFoundException' with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Resource not found (resource=thumbnail-service-1).",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

It shouldn't be trying to find the topic, I want to create it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have presented isn't trying to create the Pub/Sub topic, it is trying to get an existing topic. If you want to create a topic, you need to call [`createTopic`](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/admin#pubsub_create_topic-php):

```
use Google\Cloud\PubSub\PubSubClient;

$pubsub = new PubSubClient(['projectId' => $projectId]);
$topic = $pubsub->createTopic($topicName);
```

Once the topic is created, you should be able to call `createNotification` with the topic name.

Answer (score 1):

You are not authorizing the PubSub client:

Change this section of your code:

```
$pubSub = new PubSubClient(
   [ 'projectId' => "MY PROJECT ID" ]
);
```

To:

```
$pubSub = new PubSubClient(
   [ 'projectId' => "MY PROJECT ID",
   'keyFile'     => json_decode(file_get_contents("PATH TO MY KEYFILE", true) ]
);
```

Your code is missing closing array brackets `]`. I assume that this is a copy-paste typo as PHP would print an error in this case.

Note: I prefer to use `KeyFilePath` instead of `KeyFile`. The code is easier to read.

```
$pubSub = new PubSubClient([
   'projectId'   => "MY PROJECT ID",
   'keyFilePath' => "/path/to/service-account.json"
]);
```

Next, verify that the Topic Name actually exists.